# regex in python : shortest non overlapping matches

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to parse a string such as `"ABCeRIsqABCSDABCsde"` in order to extract `"ABCeRIisq"`, `"ABCSD"` and `"ABCsde"`.

I've managed to get the first occurrences with a lookahead assertion :

```py
re.findall("ABC.*?(?=ABC)","ABCeRIsqABCSDABCsde")

['ABCeRIisq', 'ABCSD']
```

How can I get all the occurrences? Is there any way do this without lookahead ?

Thanks!

Comment: Use `r'ABC\S*?(?=ABC|$)'`

Comment: Sure, that works, thanks. It still uses lookahead...

Comment: It is the alternation operator that matters here, and the end of string `$` anchor.